# AdSense blocking by category: the numbers don't add up?

Tags: google-adsense

At the top level, the Finance category is shown as performing badly:

- Finance: impressions 8.1%, income 4.9%

I go in, and I see the following sub-categories:

- Credit & Lending: impressions 0.9%, income 4.9%
- Insurance: impressions 0.2%, income 0.0%
- Investing: impressions 0.4%, income 0.0%

This makes no sense. Where is the category that produces the missing 6.6% of impressions that result in zero income, and how do I block them?

Are these ads that are in Finance but not Credit & Lending, making them unblockable?

Answer (score 1):

The remaining impressions under "Finance" aren't in the "General" section.  They are in "Sensitive" under "Get Rich Quick".

You also appear to be missing some sub-categories under Finance.  My account has 10 subcategories:

```
Accounting & Auditing
Banking
Business Finance
Business News & Media
Credit & Lending
Financial Planning & Management
Grants, Scholarships & Financial Aid
Insurance
Investing
Money Transfer & Wire Services
```